# When I use List() from collect (...) in the rule file , then Optaplanner unable to remove ConstraintMatch

Tags: drools, optaplanner

When I use `List()` from collect (...) in the rule file , then Optaplanner unable to remove ConstraintMatch

```
then
    $staff : StaffAssignment(shiftType != null)
            $li : HashSet()
                    from collect (
                        TimeSetDto(timeSet != null) from $staff.getTimeSet()
                    )
then
```

Comment: Do you have equals and hashcode implementations on your domain objects involved?

Answer (score 0):

Using collections in rules is often problematic with OptaPlanner, as the collection's hashCode() will change every time an object is added or removed.
This confuses OptaPlanner's constraint matching algorithm and leads to the exception you're seeing.

In OptaPlanner 8.3.0, we have made some changes that may (or may not) help solve the problem. In the meantime, there are two workarounds:

- Disable constraint matching or
- do not use collections in your rules.